# Subdirectory install error

Tags: theme-development, installation

I'm seeing the error

> the theme directory "twentyfifteen" does not exist

for the twentyfifteen theme after trying a WordPress subdirectory install for the first time.

[image]

I can access the admin panel ok at `mysite.com/wp/wp-admin` but the home page is blank (Not a WSOD 500 error but a 200 OK)

I've enabled `WP_DEBUG` but can't find anything useful in the logs. WordPress version is 4.1

UPDATE

I also have wp-content in the document root directory. My file structure looks like this

```
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- index.html
|-- index.php
|-- vendor
|-- wp
|-- wp-config.php
`-- wp-content
```

Comment: Make sure there is a theme "twentyfifteen" in `mysite.com/wp/wp-content/themes` folder.

Comment: @Roberthue thanks I forgot to mention that I moved wp-content too :-/

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to define the location of wp-content in my wp-config.php :

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/plugins' );
```